# socket.io join multiple rooms at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Is there a way to join multiple rooms with socket.io at the same time?

I have the following:

```
button1 = room1
button2 = room2
button3 = room3
```

Once I click on one of the buttons I join the room

```
socket.join(room1);
```

but the problem is that it can only be in one room at a time.
If I'm in room1 and some one writes me something in room2 I would not be able to see the message when I go back to room2.

So my question is how can I recive messages from all of the rooms I clicked on?

(This is supposed to be like a messaging service. once you clicked on the accept button it connects you to the user to chat with him, but you can still recieve messages from other users you accepted previously)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure there is no page reload. If the page reloads, socket losses connection and all rooms are left.. Or better u can add your code for a more broad approach 
Or better you can save the rooms in array and loop in that array to join all of them at once